# Function create and call

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

I created this function, but once i try to call it, i get an error.

Function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_email (
    p_user IN users.user_id%TYPE
) RETURN BOOLEAN AS
    p_email users.email%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT
        email
    INTO p_email
    FROM
        users
    WHERE
        user_id = p_user;

    IF p_email IS NULL THEN
        RETURN false;
    ELSE
        RETURN true;
    END IF;
END check_email;
```

Calling the function:

```
declare
result boolean := check_email(1);  
begin
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(result);
end;
```

Error: 
**PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PUT_LINE'**

Answer (score 3):

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE expects a VARCHAR2 argument, not a Boolean.  You can do this:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (case when result then 'true' else 'false' end);
```

Or you might build a separate function e.g. `bool_to_char` so that you can just write:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (bool_to_char(result));
```